# Confusing, can a motor on a moving disc stop the disc?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

I've been troubled trying to solve this problem.

If a motor is fixed on a moving rotating disc and the motor's rotor has another disc attached to it. What would happen if we attached the motor's disc to the the disc its on and powered the motor's to rotate the disc opposite to the disc that the motor is moving on?

What would be the result, I couldn't figure it out. Would the system stop? If the torque of the disc= torque of the motor's disc.

EDIT: The motor is placed vertical on the disc, and the motor's attached disc(on the rotor) has the same diameter is the one it's placed on.

Comment: Not a physics answer, but should put things in perspective https://xkcd.com/162/

Comment: Could you add a drawing to your question?

Comment: If you mean the **Motor** is fixed to the first disc and its  **shaft** to the second, but the two discs are not in contact, then you can stop the first disc by making the motor apply equal and opposite angular momentum to the second disc.

Answer (score 1):

If the `motor is fixed on a moving rotating disc` there can only be one result. If you attach the rotor from the engine to the platform, then either the rotor or the platform (or the engine) will tear itself apart.

It doesn't matter if that platform is moving or not.

See my drawing; if I glued the rotor disc to the platform, it cannot rotate. If it is forced to rotate anyways, something will break. I might have misunderstood your question, so please let me know if that's the case.

**Edit**

After your edit of the question my drawing needs a small change, but the same principle still holds. The reason is the effect of **Newton's 3rd law**!

Any force applied causes an equal and opposite force. So the engine apply a force (a torque) *one way* will itself be forced *the other way* around. Since the engine is fixed to the bottom disc, this force is transfered on to this disc.

So the bottom disc experiences both forces, which are equal and opposite in direction - and so there is no net force and no change of it's motion.

The ***only*** result from this will be that the fixed parts eventually get unfixed by being damaged, scewed, twisted and broken. If the discs are very strong, this may happen within the engine, permanently damaging gears etc.

[image]

Comment: Ow I forgot this important detail, assume the motor is placed vertical, and the disc's diameter = the disc it's placed on.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: Also, the way the disc's are attached to one another could be by small metal bars fixing them together. By they are both placed vertical to on another(on the y-axis) and in between is the motor that is fixed to the bottom disc. While the top disc(attached to the motor) is attached(or connected) to that bottom disc and applying a torque opposite to it. So I guess, the system would then be force to stay at rest?

Comment: Still same story. Nothing will move. From the engines point of view, the bottom disc is stationary. If the engine rotates a disc the opposite way, and you fix the discs together, then something will break (or the engine will stop). It will not interfere with the bottom disc's rotation.

Comment: why wouldn't it effect the disc's rotation at all?

Comment: Because from the engines point of view, the disc is stationary. If you put your hands in the Earth and try to make it turn around, you will be unable to do that because you are making the push from the Earth. That is Newtons third law. If you try to push in one direction, there is an equal push in the opposite direction.

Comment: Edit added to the answer - I hope this makes it clearer.

Comment: Wanted to add a twist here(to see how will I understand newton's 3rd law) to that same system. Lets say that the disc above the motor is independently moving(while the motor is off) as the same speed(and torque) of the bottom disc, and is not attached to the bottom disc(only the motor is), now you have two discs rotating opposite to one another and the motor in-between rotating with the bottom disc. Lets say we activated the motor now to oppose the disc above(the one attached to the motor's shaft) what would be the result?

Comment: My answer would be: Since the motor applies an equal and opposite torque to the upper disc it cancels its motion and now at rest, and because the reaction forces of the motor&upperdisc are applied to the bottom disc in opposition due to their opposing actions, they cancel, and they all move in the same direction as the bottom disc(motor&upper disc attached to it). Am I correct here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the motor to slow and stop the disk, but you have to have (1) Alignment of the motor and its load angular momentum with the disk's angular momentum, and (2) enough motor load (moment of inertia) and motor speed to fully transfer the disk's angular momentum into the motor and load.

The process of momentum transfer is done all the time on spacecraft using [reaction wheels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_wheel) or [control moment gyros](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_moment_gyroscope). Typically an initially spin-stabilized satellite is de-spinned to a slower rotation rate, and then the reaction wheels take over to slow the spin to a stop.

Typically 3 reactions wheels or more, aligned on different axes are used so that spin rates can be controlled in all possible axes.

Over time the reaction wheels are used to keep the attitude of the satellite stable and pointing in some particular direction - against disturbances such as planetary magnetic perturbations, upper atmosphere wind disturbance if the satellite is in low earth orbit, and solar wind pressures. So the wheels over time build up angular momentum. Before the wheels 'saturate' at their maximum speed, the satellite will 'dump' momentum by despinning the wheels against propulsion system applied torque.

Comment: Yes, I know that can be done simply by placing the motor's load next to the disc(similar to two gears placed next to one another). However, what puzzles me is the reaction forces. If the disc oppose the motor and the motor opposes the disc what reaction forces are there? One on the motor(rotating it opposite to the torque it applies to the disc) and one on the disc( rotating it opposite to the torque it applies/has). I think...